# How can I access react redux state in index.js file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using redux for statemanagement in react project and I access redux reducer file states in components like this :

Component.js

```
import { buyItem } from './itemActions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

function Comp(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h3>{props.numOfItems}</h3>
            <button onClick={() => props.buyItem('red')}>
                Click
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}

const mapState = (state) => {
    return {
        numOfItems: state.numOfItems
    };
};

const mapDis = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        buyItem: (name) => dispatch(buyItem(name))
    };
};

export default connect(mapState, mapDis)(Component);
```

And this is the reducer file which holds all the states :

```
import { BUY_ITEM } from './itemTypes';

const initialState = {
    numOfItems: 0,
    price: 0,
}

export const itemReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case BUY_ITEM:
            return {
                ...state,
                price: state.price + state.products[action.payload].price,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default itemReducer;
```

And this is the redux action file :

```
import { BUY_ITEM } from './itemTypes';

export const buyItem = (name) => {
    return {
        type: BUY_ITEM,
        payload: name
    };
};
```

Now I want to access states and actions from index.js file but there is no export default method for it so I can import connect from redux and connect the index.js to redux .

this is the index.js file :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

How can I access states and call actions from index.js file ?

Comment: You don't have a `Provider` with a `store` yet, why do you want to access states and actions in there?

Comment: For what particular reason you want to have actions and stores in index.js. You can simply move the Provider up into index.js and have your logic in App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a comment, but it just illustrates that you're confused about redux.

```
// index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { rootReducer } from './your.root.reducer';
import { App } from './App';

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
   <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
   </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// Now inside App.js

export const App = () => {
    // ONLY NOW does it make sense to try to access the store/dispatch actions
}
```

It only makes sense to access actions/state **once you are inside a Provider's tree**

The component tree for the above looks (essentially) like this:

```
Root  
  -> Provider
    -> App // NOW IT MAKES SENSE TO ACCESS STATE
```

Comment: this is not the exact answer. because he want to access it in the index.js (Entry file of Application of react and react-native ) file where there is no provider.

Comment: @Engr.AftabUfaq what a user wants and what they think they want are often two different things

Answer (score 2):

for a react-native project u can access it like this. I was trying to access user saved location and get it like this. cheers.

```
  notifee.registerForegroundService(notification => {
  let watchId = null;
  let state = null;
  store.subscribe(listener);
  function listener() {
    state = store.getState().locationAlertReducer;
  }
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    watchId = Geolocation.watchPosition(
      position => {
        if (state.alerts.length > 0) {
          state.alerts.map((item, index) => {
            getDistance({
              from: {lat: item.coords.latitude, lng: item.coords.longitude},
              to: {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude,
              },
            }).then(distance => {
              if (parseInt(distance * 1000) < item.radius) {
                if (!item.is_notification) {
                  store.dispatch(
                    updateLocationAlertItem({
                      index: index,
                      is_in_radius: true,
                      is_notification: true,
                    }),
                  );
                  onDisplayNotification(item, distance);
                }
              } else {
                store.dispatch(
                  updateLocationAlertItem({
                    index: index,
                    is_in_radius: false,
                    is_notification: false,
                  }),
                );
                console.log('No Notificaion Send');
              }
            });
          });
        }
      },
      error => {},
      {enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 15000},
    );

    const unsubscribe = notifee.onForegroundEvent(async ({type, detail}) => {
      if (type === EventType.ACTION_PRESS && detail.pressAction.id === 'stop') {
        Geolocation.clearWatch(watchId);
        await notifee.stopForegroundService();
        unsubscribe();
        resolve();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, can I ask this question: Why u using subscriber function instead of access store state directly like this in watchLocation, eg: ***store.getState().locationAlertReducer***

Comment: with this we can get updated state from store.

Comment: I still do not know why? for example: If I replace this line ***if (state.alerts.length > 0) {*** = ***store.getState().locationAlertReducer***, does it's difference?

Comment: if alerts got updated then u cant get the updated state. so that why i sucscribe to it.

Comment: Adds a change listener. It will be called any time an action is dispatched, and some part of the state tree may potentially have changed. You may then call getState() to read the current state tree inside the callback